# Make host application to see .so library while debugging

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

Trying to debug .so library from Eclipse C++ project under Linux. I have selected host application, but unfortunately host application is trying to find library in projects directory and not in `Debug` folder under it. And even I place host app in `Debug` folder it still search in project root folder. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the "Working directory" option under the "Arguments" tab of the debug configuration.

In general, in Linux the libraries are normally searched in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which you can also try to override under the "Environment" tab but beware to keep the standard library paths there as well). And to load a so library from the current working dir, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to contain the dot '.' path (which is not always the case - sometimes it is not included for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Debug Configurations" from the pull-down here:

[image: Debug pull-down]

Then select your program in the left hand list and on the right select the "Environment" tab.

There you need to add a new environment variable called `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Its value should be the path to your library. If you have more than one library add their paths in a colon `:` separated list.

[image]